# Increase HTTP Post maxPostSize in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've got a fairly simple Spring Boot web application, I have a single HTML page with a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. I'm getting this error:

> The multi-part request contained parameter data (excluding uploaded files) that exceeded the limit for maxPostSize set on the associated connector.

I'm using Spring Boot's default embedded tomcat server. Apparently the default `maxPostSize` value is 2 megabytes. Is there any way to edit this value? Doing so via `application.properties` would be best, rather than having to create customized beans or mess with xml files.

Comment: Whereever you have declared your multi-part resolver, you can change these things.

Comment: I haven't declared it anywhere. I'm assuming that means spring boot is automatically creating and handling it. Does that mean I can't edit it?

Comment: You can edit it. Find the multipart resolver and edit the value. If there is multipart support, I am sure you will find some configuration for it. You have not even posted your config in the main post, so no one can even point out what to change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found a solution. Add this code to the same class running SpringApplication.run.

```
// Set maxPostSize of embedded tomcat server to 10 megabytes (default is 2 MB, not large enough to support file uploads > 1.5 MB)
@Bean
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws Exception {
    return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(
                (connector) -> {
                    connector.setMaxPostSize(10000000); // 10 MB
                }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Edit: Apparently adding this to your application.properties file will also increase the maxPostSize, but I haven't tried it myself so I can't confirm.

```
multipart.maxFileSize=10Mb # Max file size.
multipart.maxRequestSize=10Mb # Max request size.
```

Comment: adding the properties works for me: multipart.maxFileSize and multipart.maxRequestSize

Comment: the `connector` solution didn't work for me, neither did the `multipart.maxFileSize`. What worked for me was `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size` from the answer below.

Comment: This solution is perfect if you need to POST (ou PUT) a payload request (not file upload) with more tem 2 MB. It's working fine to post a request with 9 MB (some form fields with some Base64 encoded files as string).

Comment: Currently, you can not import the class EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer, does it have any alternative?

Answer (score 79):

In **application.properties** file write this:

```
# Max file size.
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1Mb
# Max request size.
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

Adjust size according to your need.

---

### Update

**Note:** As of ***Spring Boot 2***, however you can now do

```
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB
# Max request size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

[Appendix A. Common application properties - Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Tried that, still gave me errors. I'm not actually uploading any files in the form, I just have a lot of input fields with values tens of thousands of characters long, and if I have too much text (more than 2MB of text) it crashes. Was hoping to increase the postMaxSize to more than 2MB to avoid this problem.

Comment: The dashes should not be included in the property names. multipart.maxRequestSize=20MB
multipart.maxFileSize=20MB

Comment: `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1Mb # Max file size. Values can use the suffixed "MB" or "KB" to indicate a Megabyte or Kilobyte size.
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb # Max request size. Values can use the suffixed "MB" or "KB" to indicate a Megabyte or Kilobyte size.`

Comment: Deprecated now :( EDIT: Nevermind, found a soluting - editing this post.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Thanks for the update. I've updated the answer. :)

Comment: For me at spring version `2.0.0.RELEASE` the old (and depricated) properties DID NOT WORK AT ALL. so you MUST use the new ones.

Comment: @userM1433372 Spring Boot does support the lower hyphen case as well, which is more readable.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 2.5.0. Spring itself doesn't complain anymore, but the Tomcat connector still throws the error.

Answer (score 25):

If you are using using *x-www-form-urlencoded* mediatype in your POST requests (as I do), the multipart property of spring-boot does not work. If your spring-boot application is also starting a tomcat, you need to set the following property in your application.properties file:

```
# Setting max size of post requests to 6MB (default: 2MB)
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=6291456
```

I could not find that information anywhere in the spring-boot documentations. Hope it helps anybody who also sticks with *x-www-form-urlencoded* encoding of the body.

Comment: Looks like it is also true for multipart requests. I use Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE with Tomcat Embed 8.5.32.I have the same error message as in question, the exception is thrown in org.apache.catalina.connector.Request because the following check succeeds: "if (postSize > maxPostSize) { ... ". And this internal maxPostSize field can only be altered with "server.tomcat.max-http-post-size" property.

Comment: @StanislavMamontov I use Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE and for me the "spring.servlet.multipart" property worked for multipart, but for x-www-form-urlencoded I had to use the "server.tomcat.max-http-post-size" property.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - the property is listed here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size as well and is called server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size now

Answer (score 19):

## Apply settings for Tomcat as well as servlet

You can set the max post size for Tomcat in `application.properties` which is set with an int as below. Just setting `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB`, as in some other answers, may not be enough.

```
# Web properties
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

# Server properties
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=100000000
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=100000000
```

Working with Spring Boot `2.0.5.RELEASE`

Comment: [**NOTE**] Since Spring Boot version **2.1.x** the Tomcat related property name is [changed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18521#issuecomment-541166463) (added the word "form") and is now the following: `server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size`. This can be already seen in the Spring Boot's official list of [Common Application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server-properties).

Comment: We can use readable format for below as well.

`# Server properties
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=10MB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=10MB`

Answer (score 8):

First, make sure you are using `spring.servlet` instead of `spring.http`.

```
---
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
```

If you have to use tomcat, you might end up creating [EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer](https://gist.github.com/dalesupa22/2b5f67afd7a8b3a39714), which is not really nice thing to do.

If you can live without tomat, you could [replace tomcat with e.g. undertow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat) and avoid this issue at all.

Comment: Undertow has the same issue so switching does not avoid this problem.  The config in this answer works with Undertow in the latest versions of Spring-Boot v1.5.9

Answer (score 6):

The error here is **not** caused by `max-file-size` or `max-request-size` ([as pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54788598/1615903)) but rather the container-specific max-http-post-size property. For tomcat (the default container), you can set:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size: 10MB
```

Jetty:

```
server.jetty.max-http-post-size: 10MB
```

Undertow:

```
server.undertow.max-http-post-size: 10MB
```

This has the same effect as OP's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726892/1615903), but via application.properties which is much more preferable.

Answer (score 6):

Spring-boot 2.2.x has changed

```
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size
```

to

```
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size
```

[spring-boot-issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18521#issuecomment-541166463)

Comment: Could you add a link to the docs, this would be awesome

Answer (score 5):

None of the solutions did work for me and most of them are just downright offtopic because OP is talking about **maxPostSize**, and not **maxFileSize** (latter gives you a different error anyway if the size is exceeded)

Solution: in /tomcat/conf/server.xml add maxPostSize="" attribute to Connector

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxPostSize="10485760"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing kind a similar issue. Where the Error I recieved is -

```
 "IllegalStateException multi-part request contained parameter data (excluding uploaded files) that exceeded the limit for maxPostSize set on the associated connector"
```

**Solution**
I have applied following property, Where using **max-http-form-post-size** property did actually worked for me  -

```
server:
  tomcat:
    max-http-form-post-size: 100000000
    max-swallow-size: 100000000
```

Along with -

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      maxFileSize: 10MB
      maxRequestSize: 10MB
```

Above configuration worked properly.

Comment: This really looks like an real answer who faced issue before. thanks @Loki

Comment: GRADLE: 
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=10000000
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=10000000

Answer (score 4):

from documentation: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

> **Tuning file upload limits**
>
> When configuring file uploads, it is often useful to set limits on the
>   size of files. Imagine trying to handle a 5GB file upload! With Spring
>   Boot, we can tune its auto-configured MultipartConfigElement with some
>   property settings.
>
> Add the following properties to your existing
>   `src/main/resources/application.properties`:
>
> `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB`
>
> `spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB`
>
> The multipart settings are constrained as follows:
>
> - `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size is set to 128KB`, meaning total
>     file size cannot exceed 128KB.
> - `spring.http.multipart.max-request-size`
>     is set to 128KB, meaning total request size for a multipart/form-data
>     cannot exceed 128KB.

Answer (score 4):

For me nothing of previous works (maybe use application with yaml is an issue here), but get ride of that issue using that:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.MultipartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;

import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;

@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.ofBytes(512000000L));
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.ofBytes(512000000L));
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is some difference when we define the properties in the `application.yaml` and `application.properties`.

In `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 256KB
      max-request-size: 256KB
```

And in `application.propeties`:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB
```

Note: Spring version 4.3 and Spring boot 1.4

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Boot >2 version, you can simply add following to the "application.properties" file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried every property and solution mentioned here. Nothing works with SpringBoot 2.7.0 for me when running `./gradlew bootRun`.

What I ended up doing was adding a custom filter.

```java
public class Application
{
   private static final int DEFAULT_LIMIT = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }

   @Bean
   public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestBodyLimitFilter> createRequestBodyLimitFilter(
         @Value("${PAYLOAD_LIMIT:" + DEFAULT_LIMIT + "}") Integer limitBytes)
   {
      FilterRegistrationBean<RequestBodyLimitFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
      registration.setFilter(new RequestBodyLimitFilter(limitBytes));
      registration.setName("RequestBodyLimitFilter");
      return registration;
   }
}
```

And `RequestBodyLimitFilter`:

````java
public class RequestBodyLimitFilter implements Filter
{
   private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RequestBodyLimitFilter.class.getName());
   private final Integer limitBytes;

   public RequestBodyLimitFilter(Integer limitBytes)
   {
      this.limitBytes = limitBytes;
   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
   {
      long contentLengthLong = request.getContentLengthLong();
      if (contentLengthLong > limitBytes)
      {
         LOG.info("Received " + contentLengthLong + " limit is " + limitBytes);
         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
         httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
         return;
      }
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the first result in Google and none of the answers has the full correct answer for Spring 2.7.x and beyond, this is what adding to `application.properties` fixed it for me:

```
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
# Max request size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

# Tomcat properties
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=10MB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=10MB
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked in yaml

```
spring:
    profiles: ....
    application:
        name:"...."
    http:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 2147483648
            max-request-size: 2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Tomcat 8

```
MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Connector,port=" + 8080);
mbeanServer.setAttribute(objectName, new Attribute("maxPostSize", 100000000));
```