# How to set maxPostSize for embedded tomcat using grails 3.1

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-3.1

I'm trying to post Base64 encoded images within one JSON to a `grails 3.1.4` backend. When the JSON reached a size greater 2 MB the `POST` operation fails.
The controller won't be called due to a broken connection pipe.

I assume that this behavior is a result of the default `maxPostSize` constraint of the embedded tomcat.

I've already set the `maxFileSize` and `maxRequestSize` parameter due to previous trouble with uploading big files. But these values doesn't affect the handling of large JSON.

```
controllers:
    upload:
      maxFileSize: ...
      maxRequestSize: ...
```

How could I set the `maxPostSize` value for the embedded tomcat used by grails?
I know how to set on standalone tomcat - but I also want to configure it for my dev environment

Comment: Grails 3 is based on Spring Boot, so following solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot should work for you

Comment: I already found this answer but hoped that there is another way to do that.