# How to send large file using Spring REST multipart in chunks (REST client)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using spring REST to write a client which will upload a file to DB.
Following is the server side controller code which I can not change :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<UploadResponseDto> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    String contentType =  file.getContentType();
    if ( contentType == null || !contentType.equalsIgnoreCase(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)) {
        contentType = APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM;
    }
    GridFSFile gridFSFile = gridFsTemplate.store(file.getInputStream(), file.getOriginalFilename(), contentType);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    String fileLocation = linkTo(FileAttachmentController.class).slash(gridFSFile.getId()).toUri().toString();
    headers.add(LOCATION, fileLocation);
    UploadResponseDto uploadResponseDto = new UploadResponseDto(file.getOriginalFilename(), fileLocation);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(uploadResponseDto, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

And my client side code for sending file is :

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
    headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    File file = new File(fileToUpload);
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(
        Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileToUpload))) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return file.getName();
        }
    };
    data.add("file", resource);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(
        data, headers);
    ResponseEntity<Map> apiResponse = null;

    apiResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
        "http://{end_point_url}",
        HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Map.class);
```

But when I use this code to send lets say 50 MB file, it throws "413 Request entity too large error"

Can somebody please help me out on how to send a large file in chunks?

Thanks & Regards,
Vikas Gite

Comment: your server is capable of accepting how much chunk at a time?this is spring boot?

Comment: Yes. I have property multipartMaxFileSize. But even though it is set to 50, I am still getting error for files less than 20MB size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase HTTP Post maxPostSize in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @VikasGite Were you able to send the file as chunks using Springtemplate? If yes, kindly point me to the code examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a size of the upload file by using

`org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver`

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(54525952); //...specify your size of file  (20971520 - 20 MB) (54525952 - 52 MB)
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Comment: add this in your existing bean creation file  or a file which extends from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Comment: Still it did not solved my problem. 413 is thrown by the server.

Comment: I am afraid, changing the size to 50MB has also not solved my error. I am trying to upload 17MB file here.Is my code correct? What do you think? Will it send in chunks?

Comment: cool @VikasGite  may be you missed something in a spring configuration and without seeing the full code how I can able to tell anything?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Okay so you have set multipartMaxFileSize, but along with this you also need to set max request size if you have a single file that's greater than 10MB

Seems you are using Spring 4.x

So config goes like

```
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize
```

[Official Source](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/#_tuning_file_upload_limits)

**Depricated:**
By default SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory buffers the request body internally.

Make it false

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
factory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
```

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE_to_3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html#bufferRequestBody)

Comment: Both maxFileSize and maxRequestSize are already set. Sorry I mentioned only one in previous comment.