# Sending Files as Chunks using Spring' RestTemplate

Tags: java, file, file-upload, inputstream

I am to invoke a POST REST API which accepts a file in its body.

If I send a few KB's file (using below code) it takes about 300 ms. And, if i send about 5 GB's of file it throws Out Of Memory Exception.

Is there a possible way to send the file as Chunks, sequentially? We are avoiding any parallel processing, at this point in time.

Any help in code or reference is highly appreciated.

```
public static Resource getTestFile() throws IOException {
    Path testFile = Paths.get(FILE_PATH);
    System.out.println("Creating and Uploading Test File: " + testFile);
    return new FileSystemResource(testFile.toFile());
}
private static void uploadSingleFile() throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file", getTestFile());

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/place";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<DataTransportResponse> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity,
                    DataTransportResponse.class);

    System.out.println("Response code: " + response.getStatusCode());
}

spring:
  application:
    name: file-manager
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 20480MB
      max-request-size: 2048MB 
application:
  seal:
    id: 104912
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it resolved through -

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());
```

Comment: This code doesn't relate to anything in your original question. Please post complete solution or at least something that is relatable to the original example

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(54525952); //...specify your size of file  (20971520 - 20 MB) (54525952 - 52 MB)
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

I have found this reference from this link [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557435/how-to-send-large-file-using-spring-rest-multipart-in-chunks-rest-client). hope it is help ful.