# Spring GET payload max size

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I have the following question. Is there an imposed limit on the size of the response returned via a GET request?

I am working on an endpoint, whose response dto may contain a String field that can hold a large value.

While testing it I came across some circumstances where the server would seemingly respond back nothing. I have tried to disable my container's (Tomcat) maxPostSize setting in hopes of getting this to run, but to no avail. At the same moment, there isn't any kind of error thrown.

I have tried searching online and from what I have read, Jackson should not be limiting the size of a returned.

Based on this does anyone have any idea as to what is the best place way of overcoming this and if there are indeed limitations what are they exactly? Of the ideas I had was to just transmit this data as raw data (not base64 encoded) but given the current architecture of what I'm building, this would imply two GET calls instead of one.

I should note that the char count of the String in question is over 8000 characters (if that serves for any information).

Comment: is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot

Comment: @hughjdavey I came across this but no, it did no help. I did increase the maxPostSize but other than that I cannot make it work.

Sending the same payload (albeit with not all the fields -- just the binary data) works fine when sent as raw data.