# How to solve FileSizeLimitExceededException in klov -Extent report

Tags: java, spring, browser-automation, extentreports

When I try to add screenshot to the klov report this exception is caught.

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field f exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.] with root cause
>
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException:
>   The field f exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

and I am using **klov0.1.1** and **extentreports-3.1.5** in windows machine.
(same configuration working in mac)

After I searched web, I put these lines in application.properties. But this is also didn't work.

```
spring.multipart.max-file-size=30MB
spring.multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration can be performed from `application.properties` file as it is the Spring Boot configuration driver.  See if this helps: [Increase HTTP Post maxPostSize in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot)