# Where to add maxPostSize = "- 1" in Apache2 to send larger content?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache, tomcat

When I send more content to the server via formData in React,
 I get this error in the Spring app:

[image]

**I only have Apache2 installed on the VPS, and I don't know if I need to install Tomcat separately, because I don't have a server.xml file at the moment, so I don't know where to add maxPostSize = "- 1" to the Connector?** *I'm a beginner in this.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase HTTP Post maxPostSize in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz Oh, thank you so much, I didn't find this link, I'll try

Comment: Look in particular at the `server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size` property (which sets the `maxPostSize` property on the connector).