# After increasing mutlipart max file size: exceeded the limit for maxPostSize set on the associated connector

Tags: spring-boot, multipart

I'm using Spring Boot 3

I've managed to find out how to increase the limit on the multipart upload file:

```
  spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
  spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

However, after setting this, I'm getting another error when I'm totally stuck:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The multi-part request contained
> parameter data (excluding uploaded files) that exceeded the limit for
> maxPostSize set on the associated connector   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2820)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3122)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1088)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:309)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]    at
> jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]   at
> org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest.getParameter(StrictHttpFirewall.java:769)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]    at
> jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:149)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]   at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.getMatchingRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:104)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:61)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]

I was trying to apply the solution from [Increase HTTP Post maxPostSize in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot) however without success

The parameters:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=100000000
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=100000000
```

were ignored

and when I've tried to apply the gist from the following answer (https://gist.github.com/dalesupa22/2b5f67afd7a8b3a39714) I've found out not having the referenced classes (eg. EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer) in my classpath.

How to configure file upload correctly with Spring Boot 3?

Answer (score 3):

Try this configuration key:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size: 20MB
```

it worked for me.

I founded here: https://lightrun.com/answers/spring-projects-spring-boot-it-is-unclear-that-servertomcatmax-http-post-size-and-serverjettymax-http-post-size-only-apply-t